# how to avoid substrings

Tags: python, regex, string

I currently process sections of a string like this:

```
for (i, j) in huge_list_of_indices:
    process(huge_text_block[i:j])
```

I want to avoid the overhead of generating these temporary substrings. Any ideas? Perhaps a wrapper that somehow uses index offsets? This is currently my bottleneck.

Note that *process()* is another python module that expects a string as input.

**Edit:**

A few people doubt there is a problem. Here are some sample results:

```
import time
import string
text = string.letters * 1000

def timeit(fn):
    t1 = time.time()
    for i in range(len(text)):
        fn(i)
    t2 = time.time()
    print '%s took %0.3f ms' % (fn.func_name, (t2-t1) * 1000)

def test_1(i):
    return text[i:]

def test_2(i):
    return text[:]

def test_3(i):
    return text

timeit(test_1)
timeit(test_2)
timeit(test_3)
```

Output:

```
test_1 took 972.046 ms
test_2 took 47.620 ms
test_3 took 43.457 ms
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track with a wrapper that uses the index offsets. What have you tried so far? Actually, how do you know that Python isn't *already* doing this for you?

Comment: how are you going to pass a series of small strings without creating the small strings temporarily?

Comment: ideally like I would in C, with pointers

Comment: just one heads-up: how about the algorithmic part? Could you sort `huge_list_of_indices` and work on the algorithm inside `process(...)` to save repetitive work on overlapping substrings?

Comment: @lunixbochs - If objects are implemented in C (like strings) and expose the buffer/memoryview API you basically do the way Richard imagined... (with pointers to the the object data - although you don't call them that way in Python [see my answer for an example]).

Comment: ``text[i:]`` creates a new object, ``text[:]`` and ``text`` don't, then it's evident that the execution of **test_1()** is longer than the two other functions' ones, I had no doubt about this point. But that's only the description of your concern, and the reason of your question.

Comment: I don't deny the problem, I pretend that, as your question is formulated, it has no solution. Your question gives no indication that you are ready to change the code in the function **process()** . Hence if this function must receive an object of type string as an argument, you can't avoid to create the required substrings ! I say no more than that. That's my opinion, maybe I don't understand the problem.

Comment: By the way, your comparison isn't pertinent. With ``for i in range(len(text))``, the string **text[i:]** returned by **test_1()** is progressively shorter and shorter, while the string **text[:]** returned by **test_2()** is of constant length. Doing so, the comparison measures the difference of execution's time due to slicing AND length of the returned object.

Comment: To put in evidence the influence of the slicing, you must compare functions that return strings of same length: define ``text = string.letters * 1000`` and ``cut_text = text[1:]`` and then make **test_1()** to return **text[1:]**, and **test_3()** to return **cut_text**

Comment: Even if your assertion is true @eyquem (that returning the string takes time varying with string length) then OP's assertion is still true -- that there is a cost to using slices which could be avoided.

Comment: @tobyodavies I have already agreed with you, I wrote in my first comment above: _"text[i:] creates a new object, text[:] and text don't, then it's evident that the execution of test_1()_ (that returns text[i:]) _is longer than the two other functions' ones"_ (that return text[:] and text). This point has no major importance for the problem but I pointed it out: 1) because of liking of exactness 2) to hint that OP may lack for clear idea concerning his problem similarly to his lack for clear idea about the manner to perform a time comparison

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I think what you are looking for are [buffers](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#buffer).**

The characteristic of buffers is that they "slice" an object supporting the buffer interface *without copying its content*, but essentially opening a "window" on the sliced object content. Some more technical explanation is available [here](http://docs.python.org/c-api/buffer.html). An excerpt:

> Python objects implemented in C can export a group of functions called the “buffer interface.” These functions can be used by an object to expose its data in a raw, byte-oriented format. Clients of the object can use the buffer interface to access the object data directly, without needing to copy it first.

In your case the code should look more or less like this:

```
>>> s = 'Hugely_long_string_not_to_be_copied'
>>> ij = [(0, 3), (6, 9), (12, 18)]
>>> for i, j in ij:
...     print buffer(s, i, j-i)  # Should become process(...)
Hug
_lo
string
```

HTH!

Comment: this looks very promising - will investigate

Comment: excellent - buffers can be treated as strings in the way I need

Answer (score 3):

A wrapper that uses index offsets to a mmap object could work, yes.

But before you do that, are you sure that generating these substrings are a problem? Don't optimize before you have found out where the time and memory actually goes. I wouldn't expect this to be a significant problem.

Comment: I agree that it should be checked that the generating of the substrings is a problem, but they certainly can be. If the slices are very large, there are a lot of slices, and the processing is relatively fast compared to the slicing, then this can be huge problem. I've personally seen instances where it is a problem.

Comment: process() is mostly just a set of regex, so quite light. How would mmap be used in this case?

Comment: @Richard : I suspect very much when you say the regex part is lighter than the slicing part. But that's just a guess. Suggestion: use `cProfile` module to compare.

Comment: @heltonbiker : no need to suspect - have added sample test output

Comment: @Richard: Noone doubts slicing takes more time than not slicing. The question is if the slicing actually is a significant time-waster in your process. You therefore must profile your program as a whole, so you can see what takes time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python3 you can use protocol buffer and memory views. Assuming that the text is stored somewhere in the filesystem:

```
f = open(FILENAME, 'rb')
data = bytearray(os.path.getsize(FILENAME))
f.readinto(data)

mv = memoryview(data)

for (i, j) in huge_list_of_indices:
    process(mv[i:j])
```

Check also [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/28/less-copies-in-python-with-the-buffer-protocol-and-memoryviews/) article. It might be useful.

Comment: looks promising, but stuck on 2.6 for now

Comment: @Richard - memoryviews are the "RW sisters" of the "R-only" buffers. Buffers (see my answer) have been backported to 2.6, memory views to 2.7... just for you to know in case you discover you want RW capabilities at some point!

Comment: In python 2.7, the documentation of `file.readinto` says "readinto() -> Undocumented.  Don't use this; it may go away.". In python 3.2 the documentation is simply empty... Do you know what it the current plan about support in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a wrapper that uses index offsets is indeed what you are looking for.  Here is an example that does the job.  You may have to add more checks on slices (for overflow and negative indexes) depending on your needs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from collections import Sequence
from timeit import Timer

def process(s):
    return s[0], len(s)

class FakeString(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, string):
        self._string = string
        self.fake_start = 0
        self.fake_stop = len(string)

    def setFakeIndices(self, i, j):
        self.fake_start = i
        self.fake_stop = j

    def __len__(self):
        return self.fake_stop - self.fake_start

    def __getitem__(self, ii):
        if isinstance(ii, slice):
            if ii.start is None:
                start = self.fake_start
            else:
                start = ii.start + self.fake_start
            if ii.stop is None:
                stop = self.fake_stop
            else:
                stop = ii.stop + self.fake_start
            ii = slice(start,
                       stop,
                       ii.step)
        else:
            ii = ii + self.fake_start
        return self._string[ii]

def initial_method():
    r = []
    for n in xrange(1000):
        r.append(process(huge_string[1:9999999]))
    return r

def alternative_method():
    r = []
    for n in xrange(1000):
        fake_string.setFakeIndices(1, 9999999)
        r.append(process(fake_string))
    return r


if __name__ == '__main__':
    huge_string = 'ABCDEFGHIJ' * 100000
    fake_string = FakeString(huge_string)

    fake_string.setFakeIndices(5,15)
    assert fake_string[:] == huge_string[5:15]

    t = Timer(initial_method)
    print "initial_method(): %fs" % t.timeit(number=1)
```

which gives:

```
initial_method(): 1.248001s  
alternative_method(): 0.003416s
```

Comment: This is mostly just moving the cost from string creation to string access, since these wrappers will be so slow.

Comment: You are right but depending of what is done in `process()` it might be worth moving... @Richard told us the string creation is the bottleneck so I assumed that the `process()` method is light on string access (like in my example).

Answer (score 0):

The example the OP gives, will give nearly biggest performance difference between slicing and not slicing possible.

If processing actually does something that takes significant time, the problem **may** hardly exist.

Fact is OP needs to let us know what process does.  The most likely scenario is it does something significant, and therefore he should **profile his code.**

Adapted from op's example:

```
#slice_time.py

import time
import string
text = string.letters * 1000
import random
indices = range(len(text))
random.shuffle(indices)
import re


def greater_processing(a_string):
    results = re.findall('m', a_string)

def medium_processing(a_string):
    return re.search('m.*?m', a_string)                                                                              

def lesser_processing(a_string):
    return re.match('m', a_string)

def least_processing(a_string):
    return a_string

def timeit(fn, processor):
    t1 = time.time()
    for i in indices:
        fn(i, i + 1000, processor)
    t2 = time.time()
    print '%s took %0.3f ms %s' % (fn.func_name, (t2-t1) * 1000, processor.__name__)

def test_part_slice(i, j, processor):
    return processor(text[i:j])

def test_copy(i, j, processor):
    return processor(text[:])

def test_text(i, j, processor):
    return processor(text)

def test_buffer(i, j, processor):
    return processor(buffer(text, i, j - i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processors = [least_processing, lesser_processing, medium_processing, greater_processing]
    tests = [test_part_slice, test_copy, test_text, test_buffer]
    for processor in processors:
        for test in tests:
            timeit(test, processor)
```

And then the run...

```
In [494]: run slice_time.py
test_part_slice took 68.264 ms least_processing
test_copy took 42.988 ms least_processing
test_text took 33.075 ms least_processing
test_buffer took 76.770 ms least_processing
test_part_slice took 270.038 ms lesser_processing
test_copy took 197.681 ms lesser_processing
test_text took 196.716 ms lesser_processing
test_buffer took 262.288 ms lesser_processing
test_part_slice took 416.072 ms medium_processing
test_copy took 352.254 ms medium_processing
test_text took 337.971 ms medium_processing
test_buffer took 438.683 ms medium_processing
test_part_slice took 502.069 ms greater_processing
test_copy took 8149.231 ms greater_processing
test_text took 8292.333 ms greater_processing
test_buffer took 563.009 ms greater_processing
```

Notes:

Yes I tried OP's original test_1 with [i:] slice and it's much slower, making his test even more bunk.

Interesting that buffer almost always performs slightly slower then slicing.  This time there is one where it does better though!  The real test though is below and buffer seems to do better for larger substrings while slicing does better for smaller substrings.

And, yes, I do have some randomness in this test so test away and see the different results :).  It also may be interesting to changes the size of the 1000's.

So, maybe some others believe you, but **I don't**, so I'd like to know something about what **processing does** and how you came to the conclusion: "**slicing is the problem.**"

I profiled medium processing in my example and upped the string.letters multiplier to 100000 and raised the length of the slices to 10000.  Also below is one with slices of length 100.  I used cProfile for these (much less overhead then profile!).

```
test_part_slice took 77338.285 ms medium_processing
         31200019 function calls in 77.338 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   77.338   77.338 <string>:1(<module>)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 iostream.py:63(write)
  5200000    8.208    0.000   43.823    0.000 re.py:139(search)
  5200000    9.205    0.000   12.897    0.000 re.py:228(_compile)
  5200000    5.651    0.000   49.475    0.000 slice_time.py:15(medium_processing)
        1    7.901    7.901   77.338   77.338 slice_time.py:24(timeit)
  5200000   19.963    0.000   69.438    0.000 slice_time.py:31(test_part_slice)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 utf_8.py:15(decode)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_codecs.utf_8_decode}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'decode' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  5200000    3.692    0.000    3.692    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
  5200000   22.718    0.000   22.718    0.000 {method 'search' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'write' of '_io.StringIO' objects}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}


test_buffer took 58067.440 ms medium_processing
         31200103 function calls in 58.068 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   58.068   58.068 <string>:1(<module>)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:185(dumps)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 encoder.py:102(__init__)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 encoder.py:180(encode)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 encoder.py:206(iterencode)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 iostream.py:37(flush)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 iostream.py:63(write)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 iostream.py:86(_new_buffer)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 jsonapi.py:57(_squash_unicode)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 jsonapi.py:69(dumps)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 jsonutil.py:78(date_default)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 os.py:743(urandom)
  5200000    6.814    0.000   39.110    0.000 re.py:139(search)
  5200000    7.853    0.000   10.878    0.000 re.py:228(_compile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 session.py:149(msg_header)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 session.py:153(extract_header)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 session.py:315(msg_id)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 session.py:350(msg_header)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 session.py:353(msg)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 session.py:370(sign)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 session.py:385(serialize)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 session.py:437(send)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 session.py:75(<lambda>)
  5200000    4.732    0.000   43.842    0.000 slice_time.py:15(medium_processing)
        1    5.423    5.423   58.068   58.068 slice_time.py:24(timeit)
  5200000    8.802    0.000   52.645    0.000 slice_time.py:40(test_buffer)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 traitlets.py:268(__get__)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 utf_8.py:15(decode)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 uuid.py:101(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 uuid.py:197(__str__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 uuid.py:531(uuid4)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_codecs.utf_8_decode}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method now}
       18    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {locals}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {map}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'close' of '_io.StringIO' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'count' of 'list' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'decode' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'extend' of 'list' objects}
  5200001    3.025    0.000    3.025    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'getvalue' of '_io.StringIO' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
  5200000   21.418    0.000   21.418    0.000 {method 'search' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'send_multipart' of 'zmq.core.socket.Socket' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'strftime' of 'datetime.date' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'update' of 'dict' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'write' of '_io.StringIO' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.close}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.open}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.read}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}
```

Smaller slices (100 length).

```
test_part_slice took 54916.153 ms medium_processing
         31200019 function calls in 54.916 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   54.916   54.916 <string>:1(<module>)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 iostream.py:63(write)
  5200000    6.788    0.000   38.312    0.000 re.py:139(search)
  5200000    8.014    0.000   11.257    0.000 re.py:228(_compile)
  5200000    4.722    0.000   43.034    0.000 slice_time.py:15(medium_processing)
        1    5.594    5.594   54.916   54.916 slice_time.py:24(timeit)
  5200000    6.288    0.000   49.322    0.000 slice_time.py:31(test_part_slice)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 utf_8.py:15(decode)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_codecs.utf_8_decode}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'decode' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
  5200000    3.242    0.000    3.242    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
  5200000   20.268    0.000   20.268    0.000 {method 'search' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'write' of '_io.StringIO' objects}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}


test_buffer took 62019.684 ms medium_processing
         31200103 function calls in 62.020 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   62.020   62.020 <string>:1(<module>)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:185(dumps)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 encoder.py:102(__init__)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 encoder.py:180(encode)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 encoder.py:206(iterencode)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 iostream.py:37(flush)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 iostream.py:63(write)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 iostream.py:86(_new_buffer)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 jsonapi.py:57(_squash_unicode)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 jsonapi.py:69(dumps)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 jsonutil.py:78(date_default)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 os.py:743(urandom)
  5200000    7.426    0.000   41.152    0.000 re.py:139(search)
  5200000    8.470    0.000   11.628    0.000 re.py:228(_compile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 session.py:149(msg_header)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 session.py:153(extract_header)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 session.py:315(msg_id)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 session.py:350(msg_header)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 session.py:353(msg)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 session.py:370(sign)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 session.py:385(serialize)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 session.py:437(send)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 session.py:75(<lambda>)
  5200000    5.399    0.000   46.551    0.000 slice_time.py:15(medium_processing)
        1    5.958    5.958   62.020   62.020 slice_time.py:24(timeit)
  5200000    9.510    0.000   56.061    0.000 slice_time.py:40(test_buffer)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 traitlets.py:268(__get__)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 utf_8.py:15(decode)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 uuid.py:101(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 uuid.py:197(__str__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 uuid.py:531(uuid4)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_codecs.utf_8_decode}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method now}
       18    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {locals}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {map}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'close' of '_io.StringIO' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'count' of 'list' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'decode' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'extend' of 'list' objects}
  5200001    3.158    0.000    3.158    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'getvalue' of '_io.StringIO' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
  5200000   22.097    0.000   22.097    0.000 {method 'search' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'send_multipart' of 'zmq.core.socket.Socket' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'strftime' of 'datetime.date' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'update' of 'dict' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'write' of '_io.StringIO' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.close}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.open}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.read}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}
```

Answer (score -2):

> process(huge_text_block[i:j])
>
> **I want to avoid** the overhead of **generating these temporary substrings**.
>   (...)
>   Note that **process()** is another python module
>   that **expects a string as input**.

Completely contradictory.
How can you imagine to find a way for not creating what the function requires ?!

Comment: as the example shows I already have a string and am taking substrings. I am hoping there is a more efficient way.

Comment: @Richard Two lines of codes that produce an error (because process() is unknown) when executed don't constitute an example - Maybe, I didn't understand your problem. Could you explain what you mean by _"I want to avoid generating temporary substrings"_ . You said in a comment that _"process() is mostly just a set of regex"_ . As far as I understood, regexes eat nothing else than strings. Do you want to hypnotize them to make them believe they eat an inexistent string ?

Comment: I also did not define "huge_list_of_indices" in my example - was that another obstacle to understanding the problem?

Comment: No. The instruction ``for (i, j) in huge_list_of_indices`` is perfectly clear to understand what is **huge_list_of_indices** constituted of.